# PB / import CSV data in SQLite DATABASE

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I have a problem inserting data into my sqlite database
Maybe someone correct me a little, I start in this language

My code :

```
if (!class_exists('SQLite3'))
  die("SQLite : problème d'installation SQLite3.");

try {
    $db = new SQLite3('../test.db');
} catch (Exeption $e) {
    echo "SQLite3 : problème de connexion a la base de donnée." . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

if (($file = fopen('../fichiers/exemple.csv', 'r')) === FALSE)
    echo "SQLite 3 : problème ouverture fichier CSV";

$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO exemple (n1, n2, n3, date4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');

while ((! feof($file)) && ($text = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ","))) {
    $req->execute();
    echo "Valeurs insérées : $text[0]<br>";
}
fclose($file);
```

After test I read my data :

```
Valeurs insérées : nom;prenom;matricule;dateNaissance
Valeurs insérées : angeli;monique;32425439;1968-10-18
Valeurs insérées : bagault;patrice;37438294;1966-05-11
Valeurs insérées : brio;marcel;45243342;1950-01-03
Valeurs insérées : duchesne;Leaitita;78981414;1985-05-15
Valeurs insérées : doyen;daniel;32425439;1975-03-16
Valeurs insérées : dupont;camille;4875513;1967-02-03
```

But, in my sqlite database only this :

```
|||
|||
...
```

Nothing write, just the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite API does not work with `?` placeholders, you should name them implicitly. Also, delimeter in your csv is `;` and not `,`.

So, your code should be (**fixed**):

```
$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO exemple (n1, n2, n3, date4) VALUES (:n1, :n2, :n3, :date)');

while ((! feof($file)) && ($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";"))) {
    $req->bindValue(':n1', $data[0]);
    $req->bindValue(':n2', $data[1]);
    $req->bindValue(':n3', $data[2]);
    $req->bindValue(':date', $data[3]);

    $req->execute();
    echo "Valeurs insérées : $data[0]<br>";
}
```

More [info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php) about binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide `id` column in your table `exemple` you have several options.

**1. Without AUTOINCREMENT**

```php
//I should restart for insert new table
$req = $db->exec('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS exemple');

$id = 1;

//And create dbb
$req = $db->exec("CREATE TABLE exemple (id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, n1 varchar(15), n2 varchar(30), n3 varchar(30), date date)");

$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO exemple (id, n1, n2, n3, date) VALUES (:id, :n1, :n2, :n3 , :date)');

while ((! feof($file)) && ($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";"))) {
    $req->bindValue(':id', $id++, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $req->bindValue(':n1', $data[0]);
    $req->bindValue(':n2', $data[1]);
    $req->bindValue(':n3', $data[2]);
    $req->bindValue(':date', $data[3]);
    $req->execute();
    echo "Valeurs insérées : $id,$data[0],$data[1],$data[2],$data[3],<br>";
}
```

***Note:***

However, you are not required to set the value of `id` column in SQLite DB -- it may get auto-incremented implicitly via `rowid` as explained [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/)

---

**2. With AUTOINCREMENT**

```php
//I should restart for insert new table
$req = $db->exec('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS exemple');

//And create dbb
$req = $db->exec("CREATE TABLE exemple (id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, n1 varchar(15), n2 varchar(30), n3 varchar(30), date date)");

$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO exemple (n1, n2, n3, date) VALUES (:n1, :n2, :n3 , :date)');

while ((! feof($file)) && ($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";"))) {
    // no id is set explicitly
    $req->bindValue(':n1', $data[0]);
    $req->bindValue(':n2', $data[1]);
    $req->bindValue(':n3', $data[2]);
    $req->bindValue(':date', $data[3]);
    $req->execute();
    echo "Valeurs insérées : $data[0],$data[1],$data[2],$data[3],<br>";
}
```

Here, you'll need to use [function `sqlite_last_insert_rowid`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-last-insert-rowid.php) to get the `id` after the latest `INSERT` statement.